# I am having trouble with the streak and calculating the win percentage in my JavaScript game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement a stats table into my game.
Currently it's very buggy: the streak works when the if statement is true, but if I get the words correct once, the streak goes up and if I get the words correct again the streak goes up. When the statement is false the streak goes back to 0 (which I want to happen).

The problem arises when I get the words correct again, the streak does not increment anymore.

Also the win percentage sometimes works and sometimes the calculations are incorrect. Have I set the function up incorrectly?

```js
if (guessedLetters.length == figureGuessWordsLength) {
  LSdataWordle.CurrrentStreak++;
  if (LSdataWordle.CurrrentStreak >= LSdataWordle.MaxStreak) {
    LSdataWordle.MaxStreak = LSdataWordle.CurrrentStreak;
  }
  LSdataWordle.WinPercentage = (
    (parseFloat(LSdataWordle.MaxStreak) /
      parseFloat(LSdataWordle.DaysPlayed)) *
    100
  ).toFixed(2);
  window.localStorage.setItem("dataWordle", JSON.stringify(LSdataWordle));
} else {
  LSdataWordle.CurrrentStreak = 0;
  window.localStorage.setItem("dataWordle", JSON.stringify(LSdataWordle));
}
}
```

Comment: Do they not use punctuation in your neck of the woods? I added a few commas and full stops and now it at least is readable without getting mentally out of breath ;)

Comment: Also move `window.localStorage.setItem("dataWordle", JSON.stringify(LSdataWordle));` outside the if. You do the same in both casses

Comment: Can you give more context to the variables you are using? It's tough to know whether what you have is right without knowing what `guessedLetters.length`, `figureGuessWordsLength`, `LSdataWordle.CurrrentStreak`, and `LSdataWordle.MaxStreak` represent. How are you keeping track of days right now? Do you check based on which word was solved, or based on when it was solved?

Comment: What is `WinPercentage` supposed to represent? I've never seen `max streak/days played` concept before

Comment: So words are shown each day only once, the user has to guess the words one letter at a time just like hangman. So figureGuessWordsLength is the hidden word which has to be guessed and guessedLetters.length is the user input. Current streak goes up if the statement is true and max streak is calculated if you lose the streak and not guess the word.

Comment: WinPercentage is calculated by maxStreak / daysPlayed * 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I am seeing is that you aren't recalculating the win percentage on a loss. That would be why sometimes it probably doesn't make sense for you. So take that completely out of the if statements like below, as well as the `window.localstorage` call seems to be independent of any conditions.

As to figure out why it won't increment on a win after losing streak, that will come down to what `guessedLetters.length` is and what `figureGuessWordsLength` is. put a breakpoint and see if they even match on a win, because the way you posted your code is as if that is a for-sure thing, but it may not be.

```
if (guessedLetters.length == figureGuessWordsLength) {
  LSdataWordle.CurrrentStreak++;
  if (LSdataWordle.CurrrentStreak >= LSdataWordle.MaxStreak) {
    LSdataWordle.MaxStreak = LSdataWordle.CurrrentStreak;
  }
}
else {
  LSdataWordle.CurrrentStreak = 0;
}

LSdataWordle.WinPercentage = (
    (parseFloat(LSdataWordle.MaxStreak) /
      parseFloat(LSdataWordle.DaysPlayed)) *
    100
  ).toFixed(2);
window.localStorage.setItem("dataWordle", JSON.stringify(LSdataWordle));
```

Comment: I mean they do match because the streak does go up when you win, and it does not go up when you lose, The only time the streak does not go up is when you win then lose then win again!

Comment: So in that case, break on the first if statement and verify those numbers match, in the case you are referring to. Just because they match some of the time correctly does not mean they will always match when you expect them to.

Comment: okay its working, and the problem was i didnt update when the answer was wrong, thanks for the help!